# CentOS 6 is there a stable version of wine that will run IE8?

Tags: linux, internet-explorer-8, centos6

I am running through different Linux distros to find the best one for my department to switch to. There are several programs we need that can only run on Windows. Naturally, I looked to Wine for my answer. I downloaded the latest version (1.5.28) and then proceeded to install winetricks for IE8.
IE8 crashes immediately everytime. I have looked around for some answers and it appears that there are workarounds, but they are nuisances that you just have to deal with. Since this will go out to more than just my computer I would rather have a more seamless flow.
Does anyone know of a solid fix for this? Or, if not, a more stable version of Wine that doesn't barf when trying to run IE8?

Thanks for y'alls help!

Comment: an interesting question. It will probably be closed as off topic for StackOverflow.com, but would be a good fit for some of the other sister sites such as http://superuser.com/ or maybe http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ah, gotcha, didn't know how wide a range of topics could go here. Thans ya

Comment: You will do better running Windows XP under KVM (or hypervisor of choice) rather than trying to get Wine to run properly